# Converting string to short in python

Tags: java, python-2.7

Generally there is a parallel between Java and Python in how strings are converted to numbers

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(a, 2); //java
x = int(a,2) # python
```

But it does not seem to work for `short`

```
short x = Short.parseShort(a, 2); //java
x = short(a,2) # does not work in python
```

Does anyone know how to get short to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[There is no `short` data type in Python.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) Just use `int`.